# How to change default html report footer text in cucumber-protractor frame work

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor 52.2 , cucumber 3.2 and protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin 1.4.0 for report generation. I am following [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin). In my config file, I have added

```
plugins: [{
    package: require.resolve('protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin'),
    options:{
        automaticallyGenerateReport: true,  
        pageFooter: "newfooter" ,   
    }
}]
```

But still the report is displaying the default footer text.How can i change the footer text to a new value.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your settings of `cucumberOpts` in protractor conf.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade `protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin` to `1.7.0` according to the change log.  `1.4.0` not support that.

[image]

You can find change log from [here](https://github.com/wswebcreation/protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)